# Usage of Non Unique primary Index

Tags: oracle, indexing

I have Oracle tables on which non unique primary index are created. I want to know where and when these non unique primary indexes are used. Are they required? I have check the Explain Plan but found only unique Index usage.

Please help

Comment: @marc_c - you can have a primary key with no index at all. it just means that oracle will do an FTS every time it need to validate the PK.

Comment: @marc_c FYI: there are even cases where you must use a non-unique index to support the PK...for deferrable constraints: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/the-equals-operator/primary-keys#sb-pk-nonunique

Comment: @marc_s: A primary key in Oracle can be defined using a non-unique index. I guess that's what user3404611 is referring to

Answer (score 2):

To monitor index usage in oracle

```
alter index idx monitoring usage;

-- .. do some work .. 

select * from v$object_usage;
```

more [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/index-monitoring.php) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/dynviews_2079.htm#REFRN30162)